# A distance between matrixes?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have 1000 vectors, each 3D , which presents some real world particle that moving.(non leaner curve)

I would like to put these vectors into a 3 dimension `matrix-A` . Then i will get new matrixes with the same structure , and i would like to check which is the closest **in shape** to the first `matrix-A` .

By shape I mean if the curve is not in the same place, but has the exact same shape i get a grade of 100% . For example both looks like a sinus wave .

What operation should i perform on the other matrixes, to grade them based on how close their shape to the original matrix ?

Is there something like Euclidean distance for matrixes shapes ?

**edit**
What i am trying to forecast is whether a 3d signature was made by the same person. So the points might not start from the same position and might be noisy, but, as much as a human eye will know its the same man did these 2 signatures, how would the math, using matrixes know that?

Comment: So, you want the "distance" between congruent shapes to be zero?

Comment: Apparently yes, or at least grade distances in relations to the original..

Comment: take the difference of the two matrices, and see if the same vector repeat as the result over and over. well, that would take care of translation only. See if all vectors in the difference matrix lie on the same line.

Comment: Really unclear what you're trying to say.. Can you post a real answer if you have one?

Comment: The shape $[(3,9,-2),(1,0,0,),(10,-5,4),(-3,1,-2)]$ has the same structure as the shape $[(12,0,1),(3,2,3),(-2,-7,7),(4,6,1)]$ (I believe). Their difference is $[(-9,9,-3),(-2,-2,-3),(12,2,-3),(-7,-5,-3)]$. I expected all the points in their difference would lie on the same line (and then one could come up with an algorithm, based on how close the points are to being on the same line). My expectations seem to have been unfounded. Perhaps a modification would work though? First translate each shape so that its center of gravity is the origin (but might be computationally expensive).

Comment: do two circles with different radii have the same "shape"? More generally, if two figures are not congruent but are geometrically similar, do they have the same "shape"? There is a comment on the idea of "comparisons of the relative placements of the elements" at  https://books.google.com/books?id=RERsCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&dq=computational+test+if+two+figures+are+similar&source=bl&ots=AEG0H5DCjd&sig=-gGKipfSR7iMAjXyStkrLrb34Xs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7t5fasLfLAhXquIMKHQTYBgMQ6AEILzAD#v=onepage&q=computational%20test%20if%20two%20figures%20are%20similar&f=false

Comment: @Mirko Yes the circles will have the same shape, look at it as a signature that you are trying to test if this is the same signature with some degree of differece.

Comment: What you showed assuming we always compare the same vectors to each other, but since the motion is quite noisy they might have different number of points. Sorry my question was unclear, what i am trying to know is whether a 3d signature is of the same person, imagine a human look at it- he could tell that these 2 shapes/signatures are ment to be the same..

Comment: If you are comparing written signatures, you really should use machine learning algorithms instead.